# How to write regex to support alphanumeric string with only - and / special character

Tags: java

I am using below regex but it is allowing underscore(_) symbol also.

```
String regex = "^([\\w\\s/-]*)$";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Comment: `\w` (word character) includes underscore.

Comment: are you looking to `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-/][a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$

Comment: Seems that only ^[\w]*$ is enough according to java docs - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html:

\w is "A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]"

Answer (score 0):

You can test it in this link:

https://regex101.com/r/QvDjzh/1/

If you want to check your string :

```
boolean isAlphanumeric = yourStringVariable.matches("[A-Za-z0-9\\/\\-]+")
```

Your solution :

```
String regex = "[A-Za-z0-9\\/\\-]+";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
```